# CSS and external reference style sheet page

Tags: css, reference

```
<link href="../../Styles/TestSite.css" rel="stylesheet" />  // this works fine

<link href="~/Styles/TestSite.css" rel="stylesheet" />   // this has no effect on page style
```

project name is party, so project root is \party
folder name that has default.aspx page

party/demo/IO/default.aspx
party/Styles/TestSite.css

To my understanding:
~/Styles/TestSite.css  >> this gives me a relative path to the style sheet from the root of the party project... Am I right.

../../Styles/TestSite.cass >> my understanding is >> go back

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we're inside `https://www.example.com/htdocs/dir1/dir2/file.html`, we use the following slashes in front of a file path. Which stylesheet are we attempting to load?

```
/style.css → Root directory → /htdocs/style.css  
./style.css → Working directory → /htdocs/dir1/dir2/style.css  
../style.css → Up one directory → /htdocs/dir1/style.css  
../../style.css → Up two directories → /htdocs/style.css
```

I believe the tilde `~/` is used in ASP.NET for the app root (not server root, application root), and not much else.